# Finding Xpath for element which appears once mouse over is done

Tags: xpath

I am working on a project where in i have to select a theme, the theme has a "view" button which only appears once you do mouse over. I need to know if there is any way through which you can click on the image using xpath.
I had tried selecting the image first and than using action class actions,but its not working out for me.

Comment: "if there is any way through which you can click on the image using xpath" You can find element using xpath but not click it. You should use another technology for clicking web element

Comment: can you tell me which other Technology should be used?

Comment: for example [`selenium`](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp)

Comment: i have been using selenium webdriver to perform this task,              act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='thm_KCI-001']"))).perform();    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Florid')]")).click();

Answer (score 0):

act.moveToElement(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='thm_KCI-001']"))).perform();        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Florid')]")).click();

This is the xpath which i have written.